# How To Touch More Than Button Without Release Screen in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, button, touch-event

Like this

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUNz2.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUNz2.png

I want swipe on more button Without Release. This code does not working its says app stopped working

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {
     //my buttons
    Button b1, b2, b3;
    //my text view
    TextView txt;
    //my layout if you need it
     LinearLayout myl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //my buttons
         Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
         Button b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
         Button b3 = findViewById(R.id.b3);

         //text view
        TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.txt);
        //my layout if you need it
        final LinearLayout myl = findViewById(R.id.myl);


        b1.setOnTouchListener(this);
        b2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        b3.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

         if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

           //touch Events
            switch (view.getId()) {

                 //b1 touch event
                case R.id.b1:

                    txt.setText(txt.getText().toString() + b1.getText().toString());
                    break;

                //b2 touch event
                case R.id.b2:

                    txt.setText(txt.getText().toString() + b2.getText().toString());
                    break;

                   //b3 touch event
                case R.id.b3:

                    txt.setText(txt.getText().toString() + b3.getText().toString());
                    break;
         }
        }

            return false;

    }
}
```

i hope find answer in this website..thank you alot

> this code does not working its says app stopped working

Comment: you need to look for `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` instead of just `ACTION_DOWN` down only happens when the finger touches the screen, move happens subsequently when the finger moves or drags.

Answer (score 0):

When you touch on button1 even if you move to over button2 (without release), button2 will not receive any onTouchAction. Instead you can check x,y coordinates to check if user moved fingers to other buttons and do action.